# foreach element in array of images

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
var arr = [str.split(',')];
var cnt = '';
arr.forEach(function(el){
  cnt += "<img class = 'imgall' src = 'imgt/" + el + "' alt='img'>";
 });
 console.log(cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I need in console is:

```
<img class='imgall' src='imgt/01.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='imgall' src='imgt/02.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='imgall' src='imgt/03.jpg' alt='img'>
```

Any help?

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with jQuery, 2. just don't wrap the return value of [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (which is already an array) in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to wrap the result of splitting in another array (because the result of splitting is an array) and you could map the items and join them later to a single string.

```js
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
    arr = str.split(',');
    cnt = arr
        .map(function (el) {
            return '<img class="imgall" src="imgt/' + el + '" alt="img">';
        })
        .join('\n'); // take later '', without newline

console.log(cnt);
```

ES6 with a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
    result = str
        .split(',')
        .map(s => `<img class="imgall" src="imgt/${s}" alt="img">`)
        .join('\n'); // take later '', without newline

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//correct usage;
var arr = str.split(',');
```

```js
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
var arr = str.split(',');
var cnt = '';
arr.forEach(function(el){
  cnt += "<img class = 'imgall' src = 'imgt/" + el + "' alt='img'>";
 });
 console.log(cnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
var arr = str.split(',');
var cnt = '';

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
  cnt += "<img class = 'imgall' src = 'imgt/" + arr[i] + "' alt='img'>";
}

console.log(cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do with your own existing code, just remove the `[]` from `str.split(',');` because `str.split(',')` already creates an **array** so no need to wrap it with another extra array notation here. **Though I just added an extra `\n` nothing else.**

```js
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
var arr = str.split(',');//see the change here
var cnt = '';

arr.forEach(function(el) {
  cnt += "<img class = 'imgall' src = 'imgt/" + el + "' alt='img'>\n";
});
console.log(cnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a collection of DOM elements in a array, just try out this code:

```
var str = '01.jpg,02.jpg,03.jpg';
var arr = str.split(',');

var values = arr.map(function(image) {
  var img =  document.createElement('img')
  img.src = "/imgt" + image;
  img.alt = "img";
  return img;
})

console.log(values)
```